# android studio add a new module cause support-v4 function miss

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The project can run successfully before compile the moudle `compile project(':PG_Edit_SDK')`.
But when I compile it, it makes the project can not find some function in support-v4 . Such as ContextCompat:getDrawable(Context,int). I guessed the moudle has a different support-v4.jar.
I had edited the code like this:

```
compile(project(':PG_Edit_SDK')) {
    exclude module: 'support-v4', group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

But it also don't work. This is the error message:

```
Error:(200, 73) 错误: 找不到符号
符号:   方法 getDrawable(Context,int)
位置: 类 ContextCompat

......

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: How did you add the v4 to your PG_Edit_SDK module? Post both build.gradle file (library and app)

Comment: It's OK when I clean and rebuild the project, anyway, thanks a lot.